# An unhandled exception has occurred: Malformed URL in Release mode in .net core 2.0 app

Tags: release, identityserver4, .net-core-2.0, malformedurlexception

I have a `.net core 2.0` app which uses **IdentityServer 4**. it works perfectly in **development mode**. then I published it for production mode and tested. when I click a (that action has a method to generated **accesstoken**) link I got an error like below,

> An unhandled exception has occurred: Malformed URL

then error occurs here in **production(Release**) mode:

```
var disco = await IdentityModel.Client.DiscoveryClient.GetAsync(_configuration.GetSection("Settings").GetSection("DiscoveryClient").Value);
```

above `DiscoveryClient` is `http` not `https`
here is the full description of the error ..

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
      An unhandled exception has occurred: Malformed URL
System.InvalidOperationException: Malformed URL
   at IdentityModel.Client.DiscoveryClient.ParseUrl(String input)
   at IdentityModel.Client.DiscoveryClient..ctor(String authority, HttpMessageHandler innerHandler)
   at IdentityModel.Client.DiscoveryClient.<GetAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

is this because 'https'. I have no idea what is happening.hope your help with this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old post, but it still might help someone. I had this exact same issue, only that the URL that I was passing in was perfectly fine. The problem on my side was that the **IdentityServer Authority URL** was misconfigured, causing it to throw the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code snippet from [DiscoveryClient](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2/blob/release/src/IdentityModel/Client/Old/DiscoveryClient.cs)'s `ParseUrl` showing when it throws that exception:

```
public static DiscoveryEndpoint ParseUrl(string input)
{
    var success = Uri.TryCreate(input, UriKind.Absolute, out var uri);
    if (success == false)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Malformed URL");
    }

    if (!DiscoveryEndpoint.IsValidScheme(uri))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Malformed URL");
    }
```

Here is the code for [DiscoveryEndpoint](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2/blob/release/src/IdentityModel/Client/DiscoveryEndpoint.cs)'s `IsValidScheme` method:

```
public static bool IsValidScheme(Uri url)
{
    if (string.Equals(url.Scheme, "http", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
        string.Equals(url.Scheme, "https", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Based on this the exception is not thrown because the url is using `http`.

Try calling

```
new Uri(_configuration.GetSection("Settings").GetSection("DiscoveryClient").Value, UriKind.Absolute)
```

before your call to 'IdentityModel.Client.DiscoveryClient.GetAsync' so that you can see what exception is thrown by the Uri constructor.